# Parsing XML file using PowerShell

Tags: xml, powershell, parsing, xml-parsing, powershell-3.0

I am new with Powershell and I wan't to get all id's of this xml (the xml can't be changed
because ist only a illustation of my problem)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<List>
 <Person1>
    <Id>E00023</Id>
    <empName>Aadharsh</empName> 
 </Person1>
 <Person2>
    <Id>E00042</Id>
    <empName>Raksha</empName> 
 </Person2>
</List>
```

With this code I get only the Id of Person1:

```
$XMLfile = 'C:\test.xml'
[XML]$empDetails = Get-Content $XMLfile
     
foreach($module in $empDetails.List.Person1){
Write-Host "Id :" $module.Id
}
```

I tried following code, but I doesn't work :(
The Problem is that Person1 and Person2 are differnt names.
What I have to change to get all Id's?

```
$XMLfile = 'C:\test.xml'
[XML]$empDetails = Get-Content $XMLfile
 
foreach($module in $empDetails.List.$module){
Write-Host "Id :" $module.Id
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just iterate [`XmlNode.ChildNodes`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmlnode.childnodes?view=netcore-3.1):

```bsh
$XMLfile = 'C:\test.xml'

[xml]$empDetails = Get-Content -Path $XMLfile

foreach ($person in $empDetails.List.ChildNodes) {
    $person.Id
}
```

Or use [`XmlNode.SelectNodes`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmlnode.selectnodes?view=netcore-3.1) and expand `InnerText`:

```bsh
$empDetails.List.SelectNodes("//Id").InnerText
```

Output:

```
E00023
E00042
```